# Getting table of custom type as output parameter using JDBC in Oracle SQL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, ojdbc

I am writing a POC to test obtaining a table of custom type from an existing PLSQL function as an output parameter, my type is defined in both package and schema levels but my function uses the package type.

I wrote a java program that that calls this function and supposedly gets the output parameter but I keep getting an invalid argument when executing the statement. I think Java doesn't accept types defined in the package which is why the type is also defined on the schema level, noting that if I changed my function to use the schema type it works fine, but I need to keep the existing signature as it is used in other places. For the linking between schema and package type, I found that I needed to create a struct descriptor however it doesn't seem to be able to link both types. Is there something missing in the linkage or is this not achievable?

Below is the java program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("connection url", "username", "password");

        final String typeName = "R_ERROR";
        final String typeTableName = "T_ERROR";

        final StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName, connection);
        final ResultSetMetaData metaData = structDescriptor.getMetaData();

        OracleCallableStatement cstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall("begin ? := test_kc_fn(?); end;");
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, typeTableName);

        cstmt.execute();

//        Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) cstmt.getObject(2)).getArray();
//        for(Object tmp : data) {
//            Struct row = (Struct) tmp;
//            int index = 1;
//            for(Object attr : row.getAttributes()) {
//                if(index == 1) {
//                    System.out.print(metaData.getColumnName(index) + ": " + attr);
//                } else {
//                    System.out.print(metaData.getColumnName(index) + ": " + attr + " - ");
//                }
//
//                ++index;
//            }
//            System.out.println();
//        }

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

And the PLSQL codes:

```
create type r_error as object (
  rowIden varchar2(36 char),
  severity varchar2(1),
  fld varchar2(30 char),
  text varchar2(1000 char)
);

create type t_Error as table of r_error;

create or replace package pkg_kc as 
  type r_error is record (
    rowIden varchar2(36 char),
    severity varchar2(1),
    fld varchar2(30 char),
    text varchar2(1000 char)
  );

  type t_error is table of r_error index by binary_integer;

  procedure add_error(o_errorlist in out t_error, i_text varchar2);
end pkg_kc;

create or replace package body pkg_kc as 

  procedure add_error(o_errorlist in out t_error, i_text varchar2) is
    v_rowId number;
    v_row r_error;
  begin
    if o_errorlist is not null then
      v_rowId := o_errorlist.count + 1;

      v_row.rowIden := v_rowId;
      v_row.severity := 'E';
      v_row.fld := null;
      v_row.text := i_text;

      o_errorlist(v_rowId) := v_row;
    end if;
  end;
end pkg_kc;

create or replace function test_kc_fn (o_errlist out pkg_kc.t_error) return varchar2 as
begin
  pkg_kc.add_error(o_errlist, 'message 1'); 
  pkg_kc.add_error(o_errlist, 'message 2');
  pkg_kc.add_error(o_errlist, 'message 3');
  return 'F';
end;
```

Comment: You should use only database level types not package level types

Comment: Declare you procedure using type which is not from package